# Phonegap/Cordova whitelisted cross domain SSL request not working after exporting APK

Tags: android, cordova, https, whitelist

I have created a phonegap app which needs to communicate with a self signed SSL service.

I whitelisted my url in res/xml/cordova.xml like so:

`<access origin="https://www.mydomain.com" subdomains="true" />`

and this works fine when I run and build from eclipse but if I then export and sign my app and manually install the APK then the app is unable to communicate with my web service.

The communication with the server is carried out using the Sencha Touch library like so:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'https://www.mydomain.com',
        method: 'get',          
        success: function(result) {                 
        },
        failure: function(result) {         
        }           
    });
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is you are using a self-signed cert. The Android WebView does not allow by default self-signed SSL certs. [PhoneGap/Cordova overrides this in the CordovaWebViewClient class](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java#L279-298) but does not deviate its behaviour by much; if the app is debug-signed, it will `proceed` and ignore the error, otherwise it will fail.

You could change the above-linked to code in your application and make the `onReceivedSslError` method always call `handler.proceed()` - but this isn't recommended. Don't use a self-signed certificate!

Comment: Yes I got a signed SSL cert and it worked fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DeanWild I'm having the same problem too, do you ask an SSL certificate from your api provider/server and use it to sign your apk?

Comment: No you purchase an SSL cert from a provider (there are many providers, eg: http://www.verisign.com/) then you install this SSL certificate on your web server

Comment: This error might even appear when using a signed certificate, that the Chromium browser does not know. I had the problem e.G. with a signed Certificate from RapidSSL CA, GeoTrust, Inc. It worked when I used another File that was issued by GlobalSign nv-sa.
The problem appeared only in the release version ...

Answer (score 3):

I did the following to get around the restriction (currently using Cordova 1.7.0).  This is definitely inherently insecure:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends CordovaWebViewClient {

    public MyWebViewClient(DroidGap ctx) {
        super(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        // testing against getPrimaryError() or hasErrors() will fail on Honeycomb or older.
        // You might check for something different, such as specific info in the certificate,
        //if (error.getPrimaryError() == SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH) {
            handler.proceed();
        //} else {
        //    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        //}
    }
}
```

and then in the main activity:

```
@Override
public void init() {
    super.init();

    //pass in our webviewclient to override SSL error
    this.setWebViewClient(this.appView, new MyWebViewClient(this));
}
```