# Phonegap - ajax no longer works when accessing HTTPS request after exporting as signed apk

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, cordova, certificate

I know this is a duplicate post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969043/phonegap-cordova-whitelisted-cross-domain-ssl-request-not-working-after-exportin).

I just need confirmation from experts if I still really need an SSL certificate from my api provider when our app needs to access data from protected api/server.

Also, do I need to use their given SSL certificate when signing my apk instead of just using my private key?

Please let me know if the accepted answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969043/phonegap-cordova-whitelisted-cross-domain-ssl-request-not-working-after-exportin) is still true.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert but I confirm you that with latest phonegap version, sites you access using https still need to be signed from a trusted authority.

There's no link between our app signature and the https signature of the web site you want to access using https.

The rule is the same as when you access a page using https in your browser : if the site you're trying is not signed or signed by an unknown authority (like self-signed) it is blocked (the difference is that with your browser you can click ignore and access the page anyway).

If you don't want to buy a certificate for your website, you can install your own certificate on each device you want to use with your app, so the site you acces will be seen as trusted.

Check [android's doc about SSL](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html), it has quite extensive explanation.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that server-side people will give me an SSL certificate and have my app signed on it? Or they only need to adjust on their end, not on my app?

Comment: Either they buy a certificate from a trusted authority recognised by the OS and you have nothing to do, or they have to provide you a CA certificate that you will have to install on each device (on some os you can install the certificate, on others it seems you have to write native code which seems somehow complicated with phonegap). Read the link I provided, sections "Unknown certificate authority" and "Self-signed server certificate"

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me. I will mark your answer as accepted one. Will just let others to decide if I need to remove this post.