# $http.post() returns status code 0 in Device but works fine in Chrome - Cordova/Ionic platform

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am making $http.post() call to grab content from my website.

I have declared:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

in my config.xml file. Apart, the PHP file, I am making call to, have

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

My function code looks like:

```
function loadFeed() {

            $scope.show();

            $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8';

            var postUrl = 'https://wefemales.com/android/getFeed.php';
            $scope.postUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(postUrl);
            $http.post(postUrl)
                .success(function (result) {
                    $scope.hide();
                    $scope.items = eval(result.data);
                    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                })
                .error(function(status) {
                    alert(status);
                    $scope.hide();

                });
            }

            $scope.doRefresh = loadFeed;

            loadFeed();

        });
```

Now when I test the project in chrome using **ionic serve** its works all perfect, but when I test it with my Galaxy Tab 3, it returns **status code: 0**

I have spend around two days looking for the solution but still with nothing.

One more thing, my CordovaApp-debug.apk works fine though, problem comes when I sign the application using **jarsigner** and zip align it.

Please, if someone could help me out with this, that would be great.

I am new to ionic/cordova, but a quick learner.

Comment: The following links might help. [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969043/phonegap-cordova-whitelisted-cross-domain-ssl-request-not-working-after-exportin), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036260/phonegap-android-app-ajax-requests-to-https-fail-with-status-0)

Comment: You moved me 1 step ahead, atleast now I know the problem is with self signed SSL cetificate on my domain wefemales.com. 
But unfortunately this link is broken [link](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java#L279-298)

Comment: DO I have to change any piece of code in cordova.js to remove the restriction or in any other file?

Comment: I too am a newbie to the Phonegap/cordova, so have no Idea what needs to done to solve your issue. Did you check the **second** link? Found some link and thought that it might help you. sorry mate don't know whats to be done in this case. If you do find a solution do post your **detailed** answer over here so that it might help others, who are in a similar position as you. cheers!

Comment: @frank OK, so at-least, now I get my application on work.

For me, `https://` was required on the website for facebook login feature as facebook ask for https. 
For `$http.post()` calls, `https` is not required, and I could make calls to **http://mydomain...** instead. 

So I just changed **https://** to **http://** in all my URL's used in `$http.post()` method and now my app is working. 

But still that's not the solution, its a way I could manage to do it, 

If someone know how it can be done, and post up some code to make use of self signed certificates with Cordova, that would be great.